# Java: Static and thread safety in a Java EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, thread-safety

I was wondering what the implications are for using static methods in a Java EE application.

For example: There is a class that handles converting of dates, reordering of strings etc.
All methods in this class are static.
These methods are used by Servlets.

Does this mean that the static methods need to be thread safe (in that if many users are using the application at the same time and are accessing the static method at the same time that there could be some issues)?

**Edit** I would like to know about this in the context of a web application - are two users going to hit the static methods at the same time and mess with each others result (of the static method)?

Comment: About the tags : I don't think there is anything [java-ee] related here.

Comment: its a jee application with multiple users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

accessing the methods in parallel is fine, as long as there are not shared class variables; e.g. if the method declares its own stuff, you're good:

```
public static void thing() {
    String x = "";
    // do stuff with x
}
```

The above is fine.

```
String x = "";

public static void thing() {
    // do stuff with x
}
```

This one isn't.

Comment: Aka method scoped variable or local variable.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that the static methods need to be thread safe (in that
>   if many users are using the application at the same time and are
>   accessing the static method at the same time that there could be some
>   issues)?

Only if there's shared state. If you're allocating new objects on the heap for each invocation then it's not an issue.

But I never like doing this sort of thing since introducing shared state immediately means you have thread-safety issues. I prefer to create an instance of a converter/helper class (object creation normally being negligible performance-wise). That immediately means you're thread-safe (provided you're not sharing state) and each instance can (for example) be customisable upon construction, to give different behaviours where required.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there will be issues if you don't protect your static methods and they change the a state.

Consider this sample

```
public class GlobalCount {

    private int count = 0;
    public static void increment() {
       count++; // that is : count = count + 1 (which means some thread may use the old value of count when assigning)
    }
}
```

If more than one thread calls `increment`, you may lose some increments (that is you may have `count` smaller than the number of times the increment method was called.

So you have to set your method as synchronized :

```
public static synchronized void increment() {
       count++;
    }
```

If you think you don't have a shared state, be careful : many standard classes (for example [SimpleDateFormat](http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html), as you're speaking of date formatting) aren't thread safe and may fail if an instance is called from more than one thread at the same time.

So, as soon as you have a static instance accessed from more than one thread, be very careful.